# Edit dropdown attribute of Sub category

Tags: static-block, dropdown-attribute, sub-categories, dropdown-options

I am trying to fill-in the information of a product category in Magento v.1.9.4.1, however, I am unable to locate or figure out how to add an additional option under this "Dropdown" menu[image]

I was able to locate the options content by going to CMS > Static Blocks, however, when I tried to add another option, it won't reflect in the dropdown.

[image]

My questions is, how do I connect it or how do I add an option under the dropdown? Is there a way to do it in the Magento admin dashboard? Please help.

Comment: did you flush cache and reindex?

Comment: Thanks @magefms. I haven't but I'll give it a try. I am very new to Magento and I don't know how things work or how it is even connected. I'll let you know what will happen after clearing cache

Comment: @magefms its still the same. The additional option is not showing in the dropdown choices.

Comment: In which page I can do it? I want to check from my machine